# Filling graph with default values when data is missing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am tracking several variables and tracking them over time.
I create a graph where the x-axis has each hour of the day for every day.
To get that, I simply do:

```
df.myvar.astype(int).groupby(df.date_time.dt.floor("1H").agg('median')
```

Basically, for every hour of every day I have several rows, each of them with some numerical values for different variables, and I am tracking the median value and I am graphing them.

The problem is that, some variables have invalid values, so I am removing them and, in some rare cases, this removes all entries for a specific hour.

This means that, when I go to plot the graphs, since I am missing those values, I cannot overlay the graph for that variable to my general graph for which I have values for each hour.

So far I have manually solved those issues, by manually finding the hour for which the values are missing, and then by modifying the code to draw two graphs (left snd right of the missing hour).

Is there a way to do that programmatically, for example by inserting some fixed values for the hours for which all values are missing?

PLEASE NOTE:
A useful question raises the issue if interpolating would be acceptable.
Interpolate would not work, since I need to make that value easily recognisable. I do want to be aware that there is a potential issue for that hour and that all values are invalid for that variable for that specific hour.

EXAMPLE:

```
id         date_time              score
2214431 2019-02-24 01:00:40.674    ?
1412784 2019-02-24 01:17:21.234    ?
1040240 2019-02-24 01:18:17.082    ?
384646  2019-02-24 01:19:26.139  999
3199892 2019-02-24 01:24:15.368    ?
205593  2019-02-24 01:27:35.635    ?
1844551 2019-02-24 01:29:25.712    ?
3132273 2019-02-24 01:35:17.312    ?
2698183 2019-02-24 01:37:40.517    ?
1746449 2019-02-24 01:45:25.807    ?
51911   2019-02-24 01:48:00.468    ?
2513688 2019-02-24 01:52:14.997    ?
285233  2019-02-24 02:02:07.769  999
3117740 2019-02-24 02:03:55.982    ?
1884979 2019-02-24 02:10:19.762  701
3332108 2019-02-24 02:16:22.616  797
2404668 2019-02-24 02:21:08.152  536
2212820 2019-02-24 02:24:07.990  999
2650336 2019-02-24 02:24:36.984  457
570126  2019-02-24 02:25:24.268  587
2288047 2019-02-24 02:28:22.446  712
2144017 2019-02-24 02:28:48.892  530
1448679 2019-02-24 02:28:54.745  621
205518  2019-02-24 02:29:04.826  713
664708  2019-02-24 02:30:55.712  649
3220428 2019-02-24 02:31:35.816    ?
3291801 2019-02-24 02:32:12.968  499
1379368 2019-02-24 02:33:44.287  698
3224687 2019-02-24 02:33:46.440  999
```

In the example above, one can see that between 1am and 2am, score values are only 999 and ?, which are not acceptable values. So, the result of the group by leaves a blank for 1am since I need to remove them before doing the group by.

Comment: You mean like `df.interpolate`?

Comment: Actually, I would prefer to make that value easily recognisable. Interpolate would hide it and I do want to be aware that there is a potential issue for that hour and all values are invalid for that variable.

Comment: As long as you can filter for the values that you know are broken, you can then use `.loc` to set all the values to whatever you want.

Comment: That is what I have been doing manually. Look for the values that are broken, and then manually take care of it. I want to create a function that will find those values and fix it for me.